# Is there any better alternative to this situation [downcasting]

Tags: c++, oop, casting

I have came across this sticky situation here so basically I am asked to write a function that should return a pointer to a figure if the point I clicked lies in the figure and null if the point doesn't lie in any figure.

```
CFigure *ApplicationManager::GetFigure(int x, int y) const
{
    //If a figure is found return a pointer to it.
    //if this point (x,y) does not belong to any figure return NULL
    int c = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < FigCount; i++)
    {
        if (dynamic_cast<CRectangle*> (FigList[i]))
        {
            CFigure* basepointer = FigList[i];
            Point A = static_cast<CRectangle*>(basepointer)->GetCorner1();
            Point B = static_cast<CRectangle*>(basepointer)->GetCorner2();

            if ((x>=A.x && x<=B.x) || (x<=A.x && x>=B.x))
            {
                if ((y >= A.y && x <= B.y) || (y <= A.y && x >= B.y))
                {
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (dynamic_cast<CCircle*> (FigList[i]))
        {
            CFigure* basepointer = FigList[i];
            Point A = static_cast<CCircle*>(basepointer)->getCntr();
            int B = static_cast<CCircle*>(basepointer)->GetRadius();

             double distance = sqrt(pow((x - A.x), 2) + pow((y - A.y), 2));
            if (distance<=(double)B)
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
        else if (dynamic_cast<CLine*> (FigList[i]))
        {
            CFigure* basepointer = FigList[i];
            Point A = static_cast<CLine*>(basepointer)->getPoint1();
            Point B = static_cast<CLine*>(basepointer)->getpoint2();
            double distance1 = sqrt(pow((x - A.x), 2) + pow((y - A.y), 2)); //Distance from point to P1
            double distance2 = sqrt(pow((x - B.x), 2) + pow((y - B.y), 2)); //Distance from Point to P2
            double distance3 = sqrt(pow((B.x - A.x), 2) + pow((B.y - A.y), 2)); //Distance from P1 to P2
            if (distance1+distance2==distance3)
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            CFigure* basepointer = FigList[i];
            Point p1 = static_cast<CTriangle*>(basepointer)->getp1();
            Point p2 = static_cast<CTriangle*>(basepointer)->getp2();
            Point p3 = static_cast<CTriangle*>(basepointer)->getp3();
            float alpha = (((float)p2.y - (float)p3.y)*((float)x - (float)p3.x) + ((float)p3.x - (float)p2.x)*((float)y - (float)p3.y)) /
                (((float)p2.y - (float)p3.y)*((float)p1.x - (float)p3.x) + ((float)p3.x - (float)p2.x)*((float)p1.y - (float)p3.y));
            float beta = (((float)p3.y - (float)p1.y)*((float)x - (float)p3.x) + ((float)p1.x - (float)p3.x)*((float)y - (float)p3.y)) /
                (((float)p2.y - (float)p3.y)*((float)p1.x - (float)p3.x) + ((float)p3.x - (float)p2.x)*((float)p1.y - (float)p3.y));
            float gamma = 1.0f - alpha - beta;
            if (alpha>0 && beta>0 && gamma >0)
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
    }

    ///Add your code here to search for a figure given a point x,y  
    if (c==0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

}
```

as you can see, I haven't decided on what to return yet, but my question is using dynamic cast the optimum solution here?

-CLine,CTriangle,CRectangle and CCircle are all derived classes from CFigure

Comment: You should implement the hit-detection via a polymorphic method that each class implements.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I am sorry I am not following, there is already a function that detects where the user has clicked

Comment: @AhmedKh, What Oliver is saying is that what you're doing is not the right OOP technique to use. You're basically have a big switch statement on the type of the figure. A better way would be have an abstract virtual method in the `CFigure` class (let's call it `contains`) that returns a `bool` telling you if the point is in the figure or not. Then just go through FigList and call `contains` with no cast needed.

Comment: @pcarter so you're saying I should add 4 function in `Cfigure` that would check what figure is that exactly? if so Should I also use dynamic/static casting? EDIT: I mean one abstract virtual function. thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class `CFigure` add

```
virtual bool isclicked(int x, int y) = 0;
```

This is a pure virtual function. All subclasses of `CFigure` must implement it. The subclass's implementation checks whether or not the click was inside its bounds and returns true or false accordingly.

The reduces `ApplicationManager::GetFigure` to something like

```
CFigure *ApplicationManager::GetFigure(int x, int y) const
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < FigCount; i++)
    {
        if (FigList[i]->isclicked(x,y))
        {
            return FigList[i];
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Through the magic of virtual functions and polymorphism, the program will figure out which subclass's `isclicked` function needs to be called with no further effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *virtual functions* to move the processing into each derived type rather than testing the types to decide how to process them.

**See** [Virtual Functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual)

Instead of doing this:

```
struct B {};
struct D1: B {};
struct D2: B {};

// ...

void func(B* b)
{
    int c = 0;

    if(dynamic_cast<D1*>(b))
    {
        // do D1 stuff
        c = ...
    }
    else if(dynamic_cast<D2*>(b))
    {
        // do D2 stuff
        c = ...
    }
}
```

You should aim to have each sub-type know how to calculate itself:

```
struct B { virtual int calc() = 0; }; // virtual function calls derived type
struct D1: B { int calc() override { int c = 0; /* D1 calculation */ return c; } };
struct D2: B { int calc() override { int c = 0; /* D2 calculation */ return c; } };

// ...

void func(B* b)
{
    int c = b->calc(); // virtual means the correct type's function is used
}
```